# How can we make a laravel multilevel association

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cakephp, associations

I have 4 tables. I want to implement a query on one table and get data from related tables.

In CakePHP, we use `contain` but in Laravel I have no idea.

- countries,
- states,
- cities,
- locations

**Model Code**

```
class Country extends Model {
    public function states() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\State');
    }
}


class State extends Model {
    public function city() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\City');
    }
}


class City extends Model {
    public function location() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location');
    }
}

class Location extends Model {

}
```

I have to make a query on Country and I want to also retrieve the State

```
$country = Country::where('id',1);
$country->states
```

Like that, but how can I get `cities -> location` with this. Do I need to make another query manually? In CakePHP we use `contain`, but in Laravel, there is no similar keyword or functionality to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick I guess

```
$country = Country::with('states.city.location')->where('id',1)->first();
```

You will get the country of `id = 1` and it's states, and each of it's states will have the cities etc

```
dd($country->toarray()); // to check the output
```

Then use a foreach loop to fetch the states and another foreach loop inside it to fetch the cities etc

**exemple**

```
{{$country->name}}

@foreach($country->states as $state)
  {{$state->name}}
  @foreach($state->city as $city)
    {{$city->name}}
    @foreach($city->location as $location)
    {{$location->name}}
    @foreach
  @foreach
@foreach
```

Check Docs for more info : **[EAGER LOADING](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)**

Comment: $country = Country::with('states.city.location')->where('id',1)->first();

Comment: i can't understand what you mean!

Comment: You miss > in last:  ->first "Syntax Error"